# Need Ajax Sourced Data to be added to table

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am trying to add some data to a Website and i want to fetch the data from a json file. and i want to use the data from this file in whole website.

can you suggest a method that will help me to fetch it once so that i don't have to fetch multiple times. because the original file may contain more than 50,000 data.

And my json is in this format and it is stored on the server in a file named

data.json

```
[
 {
   "Department": "ABC-1",
   "Date": "03-Jan-22",
   "Name": "Jane Doe",
   "Project": 1,
   "Section": 1,
   "Task_Code": 999,
   "Time": 32,
   "Activity_Code": "1_1"
 },
 {
   "Department": "ABC-2",
   "Date": "03-Jan-22",
   "Name": "Joe Doe",
   "Project": 1,
   "Section": 1,
   "Task_Code": 93,
   "Time": 8,
   "Activity_Code": "1_1"
 },
 {
   "Department": "ABC-2",
   "Date": "03-Jan-22",
   "Name": "Jane Doe",
   "Project": 1,
   "Section": 1,
   "Task_Code": 99,
   "Time": 8,
   "Activity_Code": "1_1"
 },
 {
   "Department": "ABC-1",
   "Date": "03-Jan-22",
   "Name": "Joe Doe",
   "Project": 1,
   "Section": 1,
   "Task_Code": 98,
   "Time": 8,
   "Activity_Code": "1_1"
 },
 {
   "Department": "ABC-2",
   "Date": "03-Jan-22",
   "Name": "Joe Doe",
   "Project": 1,
   "Section": 1,
   "Task_Code": 99,
   "Time": 32,
   "Activity_Code": "1_1"
 },
 {
   "Department": "ABC-1",
   "Date": "03-Jan-22",
   "Name": "Jane Doe",
   "Project": 1,
   "Section": 1,
   "Task_Code": 93,
   "Time": 8,
   "Activity_Code": "1_1"
 }
]
```

and I have written a test hscript.js file to parse the json. and i am able to fetch the file inside the script file but when i try to call the variable inside the webpage it does not recognize variable.

index.html

```
`<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<!--script src="js/hscript.js"></script-->

</head>
<body>
File Active
<!--script type="module" src="js\index.js"></script-->

<script type="module" src="js/hscript.js"> </script>
<script >
console.log(dataset.length); /variable not returning any value
</script>


</body>`
```

hscript.js

```
fetch('../js/data.json')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => console.log(data.length)) //here i get the Console data
```

When i run the above code i get the console output as per the comment in the code.

Please help i have very less knowledge on jquery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your console.log is executed before your AJAX call is finished. You should make the following changes:

#1 Add a function called onDataReady before your hscript.js call:

```
<script>
function onDataReady(data) {
  console.log(data.length)
}
</script>
```

#2 Update your hscript.js code to call the onDataReady once data is fetched:

```
fetch('../js/data.json')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => onDataReady(data))
```